# Not Getting Click Event On List View

Tags: android

here is my click listner...

```
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
        Log.i("", "adfadf");
        Toast.makeText(ScoreListActivity.this, "Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
```

Whats wrong in this code ....\

I am not Getting Click when I click an item of LISTVIEW...

Comment: If you have any clickable elements like button or imagebuttons in your listview row xml, please set the android:focusable=false to them and then check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the following code on your list items as they are created:

```
listItem.setDescendantFocusability(FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
```